# EJB dependency injection into Servelt - WAS7

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb, websphere, websphere-7

I am trying to inject an EJB with the @EJB annotation :

- when I inject an EJB into another EJB it works fine.
- when I inject the same EJB into a servlet I got a null pointer exception (my EJB is null).

*myapp.ear* contains the following :

- *myapp.war* (where the servlet is located)
- *myapp.jar* (where the EJBs are)

EJB Interface :

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.ejb.hello;

@Local
public interface HelloEjb {
    public final static String NAME = "HelloEjb";   
    public String sayHello();
}
```

EJB Impl :

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.ejb.hello;

@Stateless(name = HelloEjb.NAME)
public class HelloEjbImpl implements HelloEjb {

    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

My Servlet :

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private HelloEjb helloEjb;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("This is my stateless session-EJB: " + helloEjb.sayHello());
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

The web.xml in the WAR has nothing spetacular, only the servlet defintion, no ejb tags :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="MyApp" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- General -->
    <display-name>My App</display-name>

    <!-- Standard Action Servlet Configuration -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mycompany.myapp.web.servlet.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Standard Action Servlet Mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The Usual Welcome File List -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

If in the servlet I use lookup, it works I am able to get the EJB :

```
helloEjb = ctx.lookup("ejblocal:com.mycompany.myapp.ejb.hello.HelloEjb");
```

I am using **Websphere 7** & **EJB 3.0**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I deployed the same ear on a Glassfish 3 server, it worked fined.

Comment: Are there errors in the console that indicate that the injection failed?  Prior to PK97815, WebSphere Application Server would put servlets into service even if injection failed.

Comment: At first glance, your code appears correct, but it looks like dependency injection is failing on WAS for some reason. Can you export your installed EAR (_Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications_, then select your application and click the _Export_ button) and review the contents of your WAR's `WEB-INF/web_merged.xml`? WAS should add the appropriate "ejb-local-ref" configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first shot is, if you specifiy a 'name' for your stateless EJB you should inject it with 'mappedName' attribute eg. '@EJB(mappedName="foo.FooRemote")'

Comment: WebSphere Application Server does not support mappedName.

Answer (score 0):

Which Fixpack are you on? Prior to FixPack 11, the dependency injection mechanism of WAS7 was shot to hell. Try upgrading to 15 (don't use the latest, 17, nasty bug working with commons-logging)